# how use navigation controller with xib in Swift

Tags: swift, model-view-controller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, xib

I have a query which is quite intriguing to me, it happens that I am learning Swift, it seems to me fantatisc the tools that xcode provides make the job a lot easier, but based on my experience in Android projects as a minimum it is recommended to use **MVC** to maintain the order of the project, same try to swift for which they recommended me to use **xib files**, it can also be used to work in groups. Until there is everything fantastic but when I tried to implement it I find it too complicated, for which I preferred to use **storyboards** but the use of libraries and other files make that when loading my storyboard file I delayed too much which is because it is loaded with enough **ViewController**. Added to this, using the **NavigationController** in storyboards is easy, it makes navigating a lot easier. My problem is how could I do this with xib files? In a moment I try to do it, but my ViewController loaded vertically and without the navigation bar and I have no idea how to develop it.

By code to load a ViewController is this way.

```
let Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let menuVC = Storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuSelectedViewController") as! MenuSelectedViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(menuVC, animated: true)
```

And by interface builder with segue

[image]

So how can I develop this **navigation bar** with xib files and my **TabBarController** ?

Answer (score 2):

You just need `UINavigationController(rootViewController: yourViewController)`

Here is an example using this

```
let yourViewController = DiscoverViewController(nibName: "yourViewController", bundle: nil)
yourViewController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "imageName")
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: yourViewController)

// TabBarController
let tabbarController = UITabBarController()
tabbarController.tabBar.tintColor = ThemeColor
tabbarController.tabBar.barTintColor = .white
tabbarController.viewControllers = [navigationController] //add your other  controllers here as needed

// Make it root or what ever you want here
self.window?.rootViewController = tabbarController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```